# How to plot the text on top of each plot rather than inside the plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df like this:

```
Name <- c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A')
Measurement <- c('Length','Length','Length','Length','Length','Length','Length','Length','Length','Length')
Meas_Avg <- c(0.125,0.150,0.122,0.177,0.145,0.135,0.180,0.133,0.174,0.149)
Tool <- c('Tool1','Tool3','Tool2','Tool3','Tool3','Tool1','Tool1','Tool2','Tool2','Tool1')

df <- data.frame(Name,Measurement,Meas_Avg,Tool)
pvalue <- 0.056
```

and I have a text "pvalue" that I manually position inside a ggplot while plotting. While this seems good for one plot, but if I were to use it for the rest of the plots, this way of doing it is not right since the values in the plot change and the boxplots move all over the plotting area. Here is my ggplot function

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Tool, y=Meas_Avg)) + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14)
        , axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold")) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "red", outlier.size=3, outlier.shape=15, fill="gray95", colour="blue") + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.6, position=position_jitter(w=0.05, h=0.0), aes(colour=Tool), size=5) + 
  facet_grid(Measurement~Name,scales = "free", space = "free") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "magenta", "dodgerblue2","green","blue","orange","black","violet")) +
  scale_size_area() +
  geom_text(data = pval_TAP_5, aes(label=paste("pvalue= ",pvalue), x=2.0, y=0.25),size=7) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size = 15, colour = "red",face="bold")
        ,strip.text.y = element_text(size = 15, colour = "red",face="bold"))
```

This obtains

[image]

I would like to plot the text "pvalue = 0.056"  on top of the plot (here in this case on top of "A" rather than manually doing it inside. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try renaming the `Name` column as below:

```
df$Name <- paste0(df$Name, "\n pvalue = ", pvalue)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that was cool. Thank you so much. I will use this logic in my large dataset.